# How to remove entire line from file?

Tags: php

This is my code

```
<?php

$configFileContents = file_get_contents('config.php');
if (!empty($configFileContents)) {
    if (strstr($configFileContents, 'define(\'APP_FTP_HOST\',')) {
        $configFileContents = preg_replace('/define\(\'APP_FTP_HOST\', .*\);/', '', $configFileContents);
    }
}
file_put_contents("config.php", $configFileContents);
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
define('APP_FTP_HOST', '1.2.3.4.5'); // Your Hostname
define('APP_FTP_PORT', '21'); // Your FTP Port
define('APP_FTP_BASE', 'xxxx');
define('APP_FTP_USER', 'xxxx'); // Your FTP User
define('APP_FTP_PASS', 'xxxx'); // Your FTP Password
define('APP_FTP_SSL', 0); //set 1 if you use FTP SSL
define('APP_FTP_USE_SFTP', 0);//set 1 if you use SFTP


?>
```

Above code removing only

```
define('APP_FTP_HOST', '1.2.3.4.5');
```

I need to remove entire line from that file ?

Comment: I would recommend not to show `IP`s, your `domain`, `password` or `username`. Unless you actually want people to mess with your stuff...

Comment: ok thanks . actuly that is not real

Comment: Kuppuraj Shanmugam I doubt that was a _fake_ IP, domain, password and username. It's okay - mistakes happen...

Comment: ok i under stand ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First match constant definition that you want to delete, then match everything until newline (inclusive):

```
$configFileContents = preg_replace('/define\(\'APP_FTP_USER.*\R/', '', $configFileContents);
```

I see you want to delete `APP_FTP_HOST` and `APP_FTP_USER` definitions, so this should work:

```
$configFileContents = file_get_contents('config.php');
$configFileContents = preg_replace('/define\(\'APP_FTP_HOST.*\R/', '', $file);
$configFileContents = preg_replace('/define\(\'APP_FTP_USER.*\R/', '', $file);
file_put_contents('config.php', $configFileContents);
```